# How to attach Visual Studio 2019 debbuger to unity debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Before with VS 2017 when I run debugging "attaches to unity and run"
Unity project starts running, but now I should run manually the project  ?

PS:  I ticked all needed tools for debbuging in VS installer .

Comment: You can start the debugger the same way. Make sure that unity is using the 2019 version.

Comment: i changed  Unity Prefrences> External Tools to VS 2019. The problem is I should run unity after I start debugging in VS2019 and it works.before with Vs 2017 it is done automatically

Answer (score 1):

Go to Debug -> Attach To Process... -> filter out the Unity Editor